# Facebook FQL Query for `is_minor` field -- special permission required?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using a FQL query to access the Facebook User table and I'm trying to access the `is_minor` column.

I know I'm submitting the FQL query properly, because all the other information I'm requesting in the query, including Birthday, is being properly returned.  However, the response for `is_minor` is always blank.  I've tested this with several users who I know for certain are minors (under 18 years old), but the field is still blank in my FQL response.

Is there a special permission that is needed in order to access this column in the FQL table??  Any one know why I'm not seeing any data for this field in the FQL response?

(I want to access this field because I want to prevent my app from processing certain actions with Users, or Friends of Users, who are minors.  In many cases the User or Friend may not have made their Birthday available through the API, so I may not be able to calculate their age myself.  I just want to know if they're 18 or older.)

Comment: *bump* did you ever find out anything?

Comment: never mind, i just found your other post. thanks!

Comment: its http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421193/is-the-is-minor-column-in-the-facebook-fql-user-table-always-null if anyone else needs it