# Is the 'is_minor' column in the Facebook FQL user table always NULL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

The Facebook FQL `user` table has a column called `is_minor`.

The Facebook platform documentation does not indicate that any special Permission is required to access the data in this column.  However, all of my attempts to get any data from this column always return NULL.  And I've tried everything I can think of...

(I have no problem accessing all sorts of other data from other columns in the FQL `user` table.)

Does anyone know... is the `is_minor` column simply not populated at all?  Has anyone had any success accessing data from this column?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turn out this is actually a bug.  Facebook has confirmed and assigned it.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/217123218363794

(Phew.  I'm not crazy.)